# Getting the Id of the newly added entity without calling SaveChanges?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to get the `Id` of the newly added entity without calling `SaveChanges`?

For e.g. in the following example, if I comment out the call to the `context.SaveChangesAsync()` as shown below, the value of `FooId` inserted into the `newBar` record will be zero.

```
var newFoo = new Foo() { ...};

context.Foos.Add(  );

// await context.SaveChangesAsync();

new Bar() { FooId = newFoo.Id, ... }

context.Bars.Add(  );

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

transaction.Commit();
```

I am using Entity Framework 6.2.0 targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: A newly added entity isn't added until `SaveChanges()` is called. Can you elaborate on the "why" you would need the ID before calling SaveChanges? Often this is along the lines of "I need the new FooId to associate with my Bar". This is normally handled by setting a reference to Foo inside your Bar, adding the Foo to the context then setting the Bar.Foo = newFoo; before calling SaveChanges and letting EF manage the FKs.

Comment: @StevePy Thank you, I already have the reference to `Foo` inside Bar. I think you just answered my question. That's why I wondered -- why did it work in the past? :-)

Comment: During SaveChanges relationship fixup will be executed, setting the FK's of all entities to be those PK's of the related navigation properties, and validate the FK's if they are exposed. As to your question: Are you 100% sure the FK value passed will be 0? If that is the case, either your mapping is incorrect or you have a fiddled around with version of EF.